# Process an image containing sections that are clickable

Tags: android, image, opencv, image-processing, imagemap

I am working with an image that contains a layout of rectangles and squares. They are not necessarily in an exact grid and some are scattered. There are about 300 in total and they need to be clickable inside the app.

So far I have tried using this ImageMap library: https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap

I wrote a program to generate an xml for some parts, but most of the image needs to be defined by hard coding the coordinates into the xml.

I have looked into some OpenCV that may be a viable option, but I am too unfamiliar with it.

Does anyone have any experience with developing something like this?

edit: This is what I have so far using the ImageMap Library

**Image Map view**

```
    //add click handler
    imageMap.addOnImageMapClickedHandler( new ImageMap.OnImageMapClickedHandler()
    {
        @Override
        public void onImageMapClicked(int id, ImageMap imageMap)
        {
            // when the area is tapped, show the name in a 
            // text bubble
            Toast.makeText( imageMap.getContext(), "Booth: " + id , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

            Log.v("Booth: ", "" + id );
        }
```

**XML used for proof of concept**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<maps xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<map name="multimap">
<area coords="935,126,963,161" id="@+id/booth36" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="905,126,933,161" id="@+id/booth37" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="875,126,903,161" id="@+id/booth38" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="845,126,873,161" id="@+id/booth39" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="815,126,843,161" id="@+id/booth40" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="785,126,813,161" id="@+id/booth41" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="755,126,783enter code here,161" id="@+id/booth42" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="725,126,753,161" id="@+id/booth43" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="695,126,723,161" id="@+id/booth44" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="665,126,693,161" id="@+id/booth45" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="635,126,663,161" id="@+id/booth46" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="605,126,633,161" id="@+id/booth47" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="575,126,603,161" id="@+id/booth48" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="545,126,573,161" id="@+id/booth49" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="515,126,543,161" id="@+id/booth50" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="485,126,513,161" id="@+id/booth51" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="455,126,483,161" id="@+id/booth52" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="425,126,453,161" id="@+id/booth53" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="395,126,423,161" id="@+id/booth54" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="365,126,393,161" id="@+id/booth55" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="335,126,363,161" id="@+id/booth56" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="305,126,333,161" id="@+id/booth57" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="275,126,303,161" id="@+id/booth58" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="245,126,273,161" id="@+id/booth59" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="215,126,243,161" id="@+id/booth60" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="185,126,213,161" id="@+id/booth61" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="155,126,183,161" id="@+id/booth62" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="125,126,153,161" id="@+id/booth63" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="95,126,123,161" id="@+id/booth64" shape="rect"/>
<area coords="65,126,93,161" id="@+id/booth65" shape="rect"/>
</map>
```

Comment: Could you post the code that you have done so far?

Comment: Does it have to be one image, or are you saying you need to produce a layout with staggered rectangles, etc?

Comment: It could be a layout with staggered rectangles, I just already have an image with the layout.